# How to limit the refresh token to be used for 1hr period

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to achieve following using KeyCloak. how can I do it? I am using node application using *keycloak-js* library.

- The JWT token should include a refresh token.
- The JWT access time should be set to two minutes, the refresh token expiry set to one hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Keycloak Administrative Console.
2. Select your Realm.
3. Go to "Tokens" tab.
4. Set desired timeout in "SSO Session Idle" param

Refresh token timeout is controlled via "SSO Session Idle" param.
Set it to 1 hour in your case.

Bear in mind that there are no refresh tokens in "Implicit flow.

Comment: The refresh token timeout is controlled by “SSO Session Idle”. For “access time”, please set Access Token Lifespan” to 2 minutes.